# IntelliJ IDEA Main Menu missing

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-20.04

After updating my Ubuntu to 20.04 this night, I noticed that my IntelliJ Main menu is missing.

The Problem is exactly the same as described here: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000667510-Main-Menu-not-showing

However:

- the `SHOW_MAIN_MENU` option shows no effect
- the shortcut workaround is not working
- the `View | Appearance: Main Menu` action  is  disabled:

[image: Main menu toggle action is disabled]

I have tried multiple reinstalls both via snap & zipped standalone. Including purges of `~/.config/JetBrains` and `~/.local/share/JetBrains` without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invoke Help | Find in action.
Type Experimental features.
Uncheck linux.native.menu.

Comment: I installed IDE later in Ubuntu20.04. Then hide the change the menu and other things to hide.

After making the changes still the menu option does not display. I even restarted IntelliJ. Did the option displayed after this or are there special keys to do it? @Horst

Comment: @AnitShresthaManandhar Petr's solution worked for me and restored the normal function of the menu. No special keys involved.

Comment: This solution is not working for ubuntu 20.04 and intellij idea 2020.2

Comment: @Prashant I have added a solution.  I hope it helps. Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

### Make Main Menu reappear IntelliJ IDEA in Ubuntu

---

### System Details:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- IntellJ IDEA Community 2020.2.3

### How the issue was created: I wanted to hide the menu

Steps:

1. Click View > Appearance
2. Uncheck Main Menu

### Solution to make the menu reappear

Steps:

1. Open folder: ~/.config/JetBrains

There could be more than one folder. I had two: IdeaIC2020.1, IdeaIC2020.2
Both has configuration xml files for the IntelliJ.

*IdeaIC2020.2* seems to be the one with the configuration for IntelliJ.

IdeaIC2020.1 must have been for previous version or previous installation. Even if this is removed, IntelliJ worked.

2. Open IdeaIC2020.2 > options > ui.lnf.xml
3. Set value to true : option name="SHOW_MAIN_MENU" value="true"

I hope this helps.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

### System Details:

---

Ubuntu 21.10
Pycharm 2023.1.2 (Community Edition)

### Steps to fix menu:

---

Shift Shift for searching 'Enable new UI' and disabling it, then restarting IDE fixed the missing menu